# plain_boxes.asy: 8.3: runtime: error

Tags: asymptote

Using `MikTeX 22.8.28`, `Asymptote 2.83`, and `Ghostscript 10.0.0`, and the compilation sequence

```
pdflatex <file_name>.tex
asy <file_name>-1.asy
pdflatex <file_name>.tex
```

the file below

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    
    \usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
    
    \begin{document}
        \begin{asy}
            size(6cm,0);
            pair pA=(0,0),pB=(2,1);
            draw(pA--pB);
        \end{asy}
    \end{document}
```

works without any problem, showing that my asymptote setup is just fine. But the code below

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}

\begin{document}
    \begin{asydef}
        // Global Asymptote definitions can be put here.
        settings.prc=true;
        import three;
        usepackage("bm");
        texpreamble("\def\V#1{\bm{#1}}");
        // One can globally override the default toolbar settings here:
        // settings.toolbar=true;
    \end{asydef}
    
    Here is a venn diagram produced with Asymptote, drawn to width 4cm:
    
    \def\A{A}
    \def\B{\V{B}}
    
    %\begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{asy}
        size(4cm,0);
        pen colour1=red;
        pen colour2=green;
        
        pair z0=(0,0);
        pair z1=(-1,0);
        pair z2=(1,0);
        real r=1.5;
        path c1=circle(z1,r);
        path c2=circle(z2,r);
        fill(c1,colour1);
        fill(c2,colour2);
        
        picture intersection=new picture;
        fill(intersection,c1,colour1+colour2);
        clip(intersection,c2);
        
        add(intersection);
        
        draw(c1);
        draw(c2);

        draw("$A$",box,z1);            
        draw("$\V{B}$",box,z2);
        
        pair z=(0,-2);
        real m=3;
        margin BigMargin=Margin(0,m*dot(unit(z1-z),unit(z0-z)));
        
        draw(Label("$A\cap B$",0),conj(z)--z0,Arrow,BigMargin);
        draw(Label("$A\cup B$",0),z--z0,Arrow,BigMargin);
        draw(z--z1,Arrow,Margin(0,m));
        draw(z--z2,Arrow,Margin(0,m));
        
        shipout(bbox(0.25cm));
        \end{asy}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

returns the following error:

```
path g=box(min(src)-h-z,max(src)+h+z); 
^ C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9/asymptote/plain_boxes.asy: 8.3: runtime:
```

and the log file partially reads as follows.

```
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/00miktex\epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2021/03/18 v2.0 Configuration of epstopdf for MiKTeX
))
\openout3 = `ggg-1.asy'.



Package asymptote Warning: file `ggg-1.tex' not found on input line 72.

[1
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: miktex seems not to work correctly when text is added. For a simpler failing example add `draw("$A$",box,pA);`  to your first example. In texlive it works and there it calls `pdflatex -jobname=test-utf8 NUL \scrollmode` to create the box at the place that fails in miktex. You could try a bug report at the miktex github.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: How did you discern that the culprit is `MikTeX`, rather than `Asysmptote` or `Ghostscript`?

Comment: I used asy -vv and then compared the output. It still can be a asymptote problem, perhaps they should call pdflatex differently, but as it works in texlive I would at first ask on the miktex site.